# Find the odd one out (at maximum one item)

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, odd-one-out

This is a set (not series or sequence):

x,y,z,x,z

Which doesn't fit?

We need the most basic and logical answer why the chosen item in the specified set doesn't fit in.

Comment: Did you make this puzzle yourself?

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a set rather than a sequence, by definition

> [repeated elements count once apiece](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)).

Thus, the set is

> x,y,z

and the odd one out is clearly

> any of them. I mean, x because it has mirror symmetry, or y because it has a descender, or z because it's a [Jordan curve](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve#Jordan), among many other reasons.